# How to convert a Blob object into a PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, blob, inputstream, outputstream

I have the following situation into a Java application.

From the database a retrieve this **Blob** object that is the representation of a PDF file on the DB:

```
Blob blobPdf = cedolinoPdf.getAllegatoBlob();
```

Now I have to convert it into a PDF file. How can I do this task?

Tnx

Comment: What do you mean? It already *is* a PDF file, or? So what do you want to do? Display it? Save it?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I need to display it into a JSP page

Comment: @AndreaNobili - if you need to display it in a web page, create a servlet (or spring MVC controller or whatever) that gets the Blob and pipes it's input stream to the servlet's output stream. Then in your page, you can create a frame (or a PDF viewer object) that points to your servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getBinaryStream() from the ResultSet, then you can create a file from InputStream returned by the getBinaryStream().

Your code may look something like this

```html
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
  
try {
         
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "sa", "sa");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT fileName,blobFile FROM tblBlobFiles");
     
     
        if (rs.next()) {
  
String filename = rs.getString(1);
           Blob blob = rs.getBlob(2);
          InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\DownloadedFiles"+ "\\" + filename);
 
int b = 0;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1)
{
    fos.write(b); 
}
        }
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.getMessage (); e.printStackTrace(); 
System.out.println(e); 
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
    e.getMessage (); e.printStackTrace(); 
System.out.println(e); 
    }
```

If you need all the blobs, do a iteration on the resultset

Answer (score 6):

If the Blob is the binary representation of a PDF, all you need to do is get the bytes. If you wanted to write the PDF to a file, you could do...

```
Blob blobPdf = ...;
File outputFile = new File("/tmp/blah/whatever.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
IOUtils.copy(blobPdf.getBinaryStream(), fout);
```

This should write your PDF to a file called "/tmp/blah/whatever.pdf"

Comment: As far as I know, `Blob` doesn't have a `getInputStream`, but a `getBinaryStream()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html

Comment: @Albert thanks for spotting that - I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java NIO

```
InputStream fileBolb = rs.getBinaryStream("columnName");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(fileBolb );
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath + fname);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
rbc.close();
```

Comment: What is Long.MAX_VALUE in this example? Is there no way to get the size of the ReadableByteChannel?

Comment: Log.MAX_VALUE is a constant holding the maximum value

Answer (score -1):

Converting Blob into PDF is not that much straight forward task.
I had used itext.5.5.9.jar to achieve same, here is my code:

```
public static void blobToPDF(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Blob blobPdf = ....;

    com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader newreader = null;

    try (InputStream targetStream = blobPdf.getBinaryStream()) {

        newreader = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader(targetStream);

        System.out.println("Reading PDF using com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader...");
        System.out.println("PDF read success with kernel package ");
        System.out.println("PDF length = " + newreader.getFileLength());

    } catch (InvalidPdfException | FileNotFoundException | SQLException ipe) {
        ipe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (newreader != null)
            newreader.close();
    }
}
```